# Space-efficient way to prove that a data has been processed before

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, optimization, trees, space-complexity

Suppose that I have a stream of data packets in the form of unsigned 64 bit integers.

And I want to make sure that I am not processing the same packet content more than once.

A way of doing this would be using a hash map or dictionary, with the packets content as the key. And before processing a packet, I would need to check if the packet content already exists in the map. However doing this way would require at least `n * 8` bytes in memory where `n` is the number of unique integers in the stream.

Is there a more space-efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't willing to tolerate any chance of error, then there is no more space-efficient way. You need enough space to store all of the data seen so far, so you need at least about $8n$ bytes (a little bit less, but not much less, for typical values of $n$).

If you're willing to tolerate a small chance of error, you could consider a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  However, I suspect it will make errors in the "wrong direction" for your needs, as there is a small chance that a new packet could be wrongly treated as a duplicate.

Comment: The information-theoretic space lower bound is $\lceil \log_2 \binom{2^{64}}{n} \rceil$ bits, which can be less than $64n$ bits.

Comment: @pcpthm, yes, good point, but not a lot smaller -- I suspect it's not a big enough difference to be useful in practice, as in practice $n$ will be much smaller than $2^{64}$, so that quantity will be close to $8n$.

Answer (score 1):

As @pcpthm indicated in a comment, you can do much better than storing $64n$ bits when you get beyond a small number of entries. The bad news is that many traditional data structures for this (e.g. inverted lists) are not well-suited for dynamic update.

Since you only need to test membership, your best bet may be to use a *succinct* hash table. The key idea is to use an *invertible* hash function.

Depending on the particulars of the data, it may be appropriate to use the hash function $h(x) = x$, which is trivially invertible. But if it's not, you can easily construct invertible hash functions by using a [Feistel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher).

Suppose the value to be hashed is interpreted as two 32-bit integers $(l_0, r_0)$, and suppose you have a collection of (probably non-invertible; could be as simple as multiplication by a large prime) hash functions $h_i$ which map 32-bit integers to 32-bit integers. Then define:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
l_{i+1} & = & r_i \\
r_{i+1} & = & l_i \oplus h_i(r_i) 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

(Note that $\oplus$ is bitwise exclusive or.)

Perform this for $k$ stages, and $(l_k,r_k)$ is your 64-bit hash value.

You can see why this hash function is invertible:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
l_i & = & r_{i+1} \oplus h_{i}(l_{i+1}) \\
r_i & = & l_{i+1} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So given all this, we now have an invertible hash function $h$. So now let's look at the actual hash table.

Imagine, for a moment, an idealised table where you store exactly $2^m$ entries in a table with $2^m$ buckets, and by pure luck, each bucket contains exactly one entry.

Traditionally, to test if $x$ is in this hash table, you would compute $h(x)$, obtain the bucket number as $b = h(x) \wedge (2^m-1)$ (where $\wedge$ is bitwise logical and), consult the $b$th bucket to see if it contains $x$.

If $h$ is invertible, you don't need to store $x$ in the bucket; it is sufficient to store $h(x)$ since if $h(x_i) = h(x_j)$, $x_i = x_j$.

However if you do that (and this is the *really* clever part), you don't need to store the $m$ lowest-order bits of $h(x)$ either, because that is implied by the fact that you are already looking in the right bucket. So you only need to store $h(x) \gg m$, which is $64-m$ bits per entry. So the total storage used by this data structure is $2^m(64-m)$ bits.

The theoretical minimum storage of any exact data structure is $\log { 2^{64} \choose 2^m }$ bits. Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$\log n! \approx n \log n - n \log e$$

we find that, if $2^m$ is much smaller than $2^{64}$, in the sense that $\log (2^{64} - 2^m) \approx 64$, then

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\log { 2^{64} \choose 2^m } & \approx & \left(2^{64} \times 64 - 2^{64} \log e\right) - \left(2^m \times m - 2^m \log e\right) \\ & & - \left((2^{64} - 2^m) \log (2^{64} - 2^m) - (2^{64} - 2^m) \log e\right) \\
& = & 2^{64} \left(64 - \log (2^{64} - 2^m)\right) + 2^m \left(\log (2^{64} - 2^m) - m\right) \\
& \approx & 2^m \left(64 - m\right)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So this representation is close to optimal.

Except, of course, that ideal hash tables where there is exactly one entry per bucket don't exist.

But there are variants where you can get quite close to full occupancy, such as [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing). Note that hash table schemes based on probing (e.g. linear or quadratic probing) will *not* work here, because an entry must live in the bucket that corresponds to its hash value.